Mongo node .find() in Next.js API route working in local env but not on Vercel
I am calling the same .find() operation on MongoDB collection. I am connected to the same MongoDB in both the development environment and production (Vercel). In development environment I get results, but in production not:
const invoices = await db
      .collection('invoices')
      .find({
        $and: [
          {company: company_regex},
          {status: status_regex},
          {country: country_regex},
        ]
      })
      .sort({_id:-1})
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(skip)
      .toArray();

The only difference is that Vercel is using Node.js v 20 locally I use 21.7.1... Could this be the reason?

did you log the '*_regex' variables immediately before the call to make sure those are the same?  Also make sure the same database is selected.

Are you using MongoDB free cluster. If yes, then it does not work if you use it for production.

@MuneebKhan yes I am using the free cluster... so what exactly doesn't work in production? Because everything else is working for me...

@Joe I did, everything is the same...

perhaps enable auditing on the mongod so you can see the exact queries that are sent
